# mysql "between date" query works in phpmyadmin but returns nothing with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

When i try to run this with php/pdo the result is empty, but when i replace the variables and echo the query and copy paste to phpmyadmin it works as it should.

I guess that it have something to do with the BETWEEN part in the query, it works if I remove it.

php code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from `activity` 
WHERE `activity`.`employee_id` = :id 
AND `activity_endtime` BETWEEN :start 
AND :end 
ORDER BY :order LIMIT 0 ,:limit';

$date_end = date('Y-m-d',time());
$date_start = date('Y-m-01',strtotime($date_end));
$values = array(
':id' => $_SESSION['user_id'], 
':start' => '"'.$date_start.'"', 
':end' => '"'.$date_end.'"',
':order' => 'activity_id', 
':limit' => '10');
$q->execute($values);

while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 //does not get here after adding the between part
}
```

The query that i get from replacing the parameters and echoing:

```
SELECT * from `activity` 
WHERE `activity`.`employee_id` = 7 
AND `activity_endtime` BETWEEN "2014-08-01" 
AND "2014-08-18" 
ORDER BY activity_id LIMIT 0 ,10
```

Comment: Since you're probably not checking for errors, add `$q->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't wrap the values with quotes.

Change

```
':start' => '"'.$date_start.'"', 
':end' => '"'.$date_end.'"',
```

to

```
':start' => $date_start, 
':end' => $date_end,
```

and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I was going to say that too @JayBlanchard but seeing the way the edits were going, figured he'd get it ;) edit: ah, deleted... you're quick

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to ommit it after copy/pasting the second time. Fixed it just after I hit the submit button. Thanks though. :)